# uninstall using registry uninstall string powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, batch-file, foreach, registry

I'm trying to create a powershell script that will uninstall all versions of a program in our studio.

I had a look at the registry and can see that we have 3 strings of the program installed in our studio computers

```
{D4BE10F2-3E2D-4120-863A-765623D53264}
{77067FD9-800C-48B4-803D-569642ADABC5}
{1DB1AEB7-EDBD-4BB1-87DB-26C72576DA42}
```

I created a test script:

```
msiexec.exe /x{D4BE10F2-3E2D-4120-863A-765623D53264} /q
```

and used it on a machine, this worked and that version of the program was uninstalled.

I want to create a script that cycle all 3 strings and Success on the correct one, as I don't know what machine has what version without doing a scan.

so I created a `powershell script:

```
foreach ($guid in '{D4BE10F2-3E2D-4120-863A-765623D53264}', 
                  '{77067FD9-800C-48B4-803D-569642ADABC5}', 
                  '{1DB1AEB7-EDBD-4BB1-87DB-26C72576DA42}') {

  $exe = 'C:\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe'

  $ps = Start-Process -PassThru -Wait $exe "/x /q" 

  if ($ps.ExitCode -eq 0) { "Success"; exit 0 }

}

Write-Warning "Uninstallation failed."
exit $ps.ExitCode
```

This is not working for me as it keeps returning with Uninstallation failed, I'm not sure whats going on.

Any advice?

Comment: You're not passing `$guid` to your `Start-Process` call: `$ps = Start-Process -PassThru -Wait $exe "/x$guid /q "`

Comment: I would prefer that you determine which, if any of the GUID's, are listed in the registry first. Then proceeed with just one uninstall command first. Also, your program 'Maya 2019', is already a `.msi` file, so its information should easily be found using WMI, _`Win32_Product`_. You may therefore be better advised to use `Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_Product`. Please see this [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/working-with-software-installations?view=powershell-7) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This will work even if there are all three versions installed:

```
foreach ($guid in '{D4BE10F2-3E2D-4120-863A-765623D53264}', 
                  '{77067FD9-800C-48B4-803D-569642ADABC5}', 
                  '{1DB1AEB7-EDBD-4BB1-87DB-26C72576DA42}') {

    $exe = 'C:\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe'
    $ps = Start-Process $exe -ArgumentList "/x$guid /q" -PassThru -Wait 
    if ($ps.ExitCode -eq 0) {
        Write-Host "$($guid): Success"
    } else {
        Write-Host "$($guid): Failed"
    }
}
```